# How to compare two 3D point clouds

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction, point-clouds, open3d

I am supposed to take 2 input point clouds and compare them to figure out if there are any differences in them in terms of lets say the location of the components, etc.

I want to know how I should compare both point clouds to get a similarity or dissimilarity score and compare it with some threshold value to check if it passes or not.

I thought of doing the feature extraction of both point clouds using **FPFH (Fast Point Feature Histograms)** method and then compare them. I don't if this is the best way or not. Then, I tried **RANSAC based feature matching** using feature vectors (generated from FPFH method) of both point clouds, but I am not getting any meaningful result.

I have no prior knowledge of working with point clouds and this is my first time working with it. What can I try next?

Comment: My 3D classes are 15 years ago, but if I remember right there were metrics like Hausdorff Distance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.